# How to prevent blank xmlns attributes in output VBA

Tags: xml, vba, dom

Good nights:

I'm making a ribbon and when I create the node root and the namespace I put it like atribute. the next node it repites the namespace in blanket

```
Code:
Private Sub crearRibbon()
    Dim RibbonXml As DOMDocument60
    Dim objRaizElem As IXMLDOMElement
    Dim objRibbonElem As IXMLDOMElement
    Dim objPestana As IXMLDOMElement
    Dim objPestanas As IXMLDOMElement
    Dim objGrupo As IXMLDOMElement
    Dim objControl As IXMLDOMElement
    Dim objRaizAtt As IXMLDOMAttribute
    Dim objRibbonAtt As IXMLDOMAttribute
    Dim objPestanaAtt As IXMLDOMAttribute
    Dim objGrupoAtt As IXMLDOMAttribute
    Dim objControlAtt As IXMLDOMAttribute
    Dim strRibbon As String
    Dim x As String
    Dim oNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement


    Set RibbonXml = New DOMDocument60

    'Raiz
    Set objRaizElem = RibbonXml.createElement("customUI")
    RibbonXml.appendChild objRaizElem
    Set objRaizAtt = RibbonXml.createAttribute("xmlns")
    objRaizAtt.Text = ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui")
    objRaizElem.setAttributeNode objRaizAtt

    'Ribbon

    Set objRibbonElem = RibbonXml.createElement("ribbon")
    objRaizElem.appendChild objRibbonElem
    Set objRibbonAtt = RibbonXml.createAttribute("startFromScratch")
    objRibbonAtt.Text = ("True")
    objRibbonElem.setAttributeNode objRibbonAtt
    Set oNode = RibbonXml.selectSingleNode("//ribbon")
    'Set oNode = RibbonXml.getElementsByTagName("/customUI/ribbon/[xmlns]")
    'oNode.removeAttribute ("xmlns")
    oNode.Attributes.removeNamedItem "xmlns"


    'Pestaña
    Set objPestana = RibbonXml.createElement("tabs")
    objRibbonElem.appendChild objPestana

    'Pestañas
    Set objPestanas = RibbonXml.createElement("tab")
    objPestana.appendChild objPestanas
    Set objPestanaAtt = RibbonXml.createAttribute("id")
    objPestanaAtt.Text = ("1")
    objPestanas.setAttributeNode objPestanaAtt
    Set objPestanaAtt = RibbonXml.createAttribute("label")
    objPestanaAtt.Text = ("A Custom Tab")
    objPestanas.setAttributeNode objPestanaAtt
    Set objPestanaAtt = RibbonXml.createAttribute("visible")
    objPestanaAtt.Text = ("true")
    objPestanas.setAttributeNode objPestanaAtt

    'Grupos
    Set objGrupo = RibbonXml.createElement("group")
    objPestanas.appendChild objGrupo
    Set objGrupoAtt = RibbonXml.createAttribute("id")
    objGrupoAtt.Text = ("dbCustomGroup")
    objGrupo.setAttributeNode objGrupoAtt
    Set objGrupoAtt = RibbonXml.createAttribute("label")
    objGrupoAtt.Text = ("A Custom Group")
    objGrupo.setAttributeNode objGrupoAtt

    'Control
    Set objControl = RibbonXml.createElement("control")
    objGrupo.appendChild objControl
    Set objControlAtt = RibbonXml.createAttribute("idMso")
    objControlAtt.Text = ("Paste")
    objControl.setAttributeNode objControlAtt
    Set objControlAtt = RibbonXml.createAttribute("label")
    objControlAtt.Text = ("Built-in Paste")
    objControl.setAttributeNode objControlAtt
    Set objControlAtt = RibbonXml.createAttribute("enabled")
    objControlAtt.Text = ("true")
    objControl.setAttributeNode objControlAtt

    RibbonXml.Save ("miRibbon1.xml")
```

End Sub

And my output

```
 <customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
<ribbon xmlns="" startFromScratch="False">
<tabs>
<tab id="1" label="A Custom Tab" visible="true">
<group id="dbCustomGroup" label="A Custom Group">
<control idMso="Paste" label="Built-in Paste" enabled="true"/>
</group>
</tab>
</tabs>
</ribbon>
</customUI>

And ribbon xmlns=""
```

it would get only ribbon

Thanks

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: What are you asking <ribbon xmlns="" startFromScratch="False"> And should be: <ribbon startFromScratch="False">

Comment: The English cost me a lot, but after the root namespace to bring the below node Ribbon node in my case, I show him the namespace <ribbon xmlns = ""
And I want you to leave me without it, only <ribbon startFromScratch = "False">
And I tried to add the item to remove IXMLDOMElement in the Ribbon node:
In September oNode = RibbonXml.selectSingleNode ("// ribbon")
oNode.Attributes.removeNamedItem "xmlns"

But does not remove itAnd I tried other ways but none of them and succeeded.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Already resolved to eliminate the space xmlns = "" instead of using createElement use CreateNode where I set the namespace.

Now:

```
    Set objPestanas = RibbonXml.createNode(1, "tab", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui")
```

Before:

```
Set objPestanas = RibbonXml.createElement("tab")
```

All full:

```
Private Sub crearRibbon()
Dim RibbonXml As DOMDocument60
Dim objRaizElem As IXMLDOMElement
Dim objRibbonElem As IXMLDOMElement
Dim objPestana As IXMLDOMElement
Dim objPestanas As IXMLDOMElement
Dim objGrupo As IXMLDOMElement
Dim objControl As IXMLDOMElement
Dim objRaizAtt As IXMLDOMAttribute
Dim objRibbonAtt As IXMLDOMAttribute
Dim objPestanaAtt As IXMLDOMAttribute
Dim objGrupoAtt As IXMLDOMAttribute
Dim objControlAtt As IXMLDOMAttribute
Dim strRibbon As String


Set RibbonXml = New DOMDocument60

'Raiz
Set objRaizElem = RibbonXml.createNode(1, "customUI", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui")
RibbonXml.appendChild objRaizElem

'Ribbon

Set objRibbonElem = RibbonXml.createNode(1, "ribbons", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui")
objRaizElem.appendChild objRibbonElem
Set objRibbonAtt = RibbonXml.createAttribute("startFromScratch")
objRibbonAtt.Text = ("True")
objRibbonElem.setAttributeNode objRibbonAtt


'Pestaña
Set objPestana = RibbonXml.createNode(1, "tabs", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui")
objRibbonElem.appendChild objPestana

'Pestañas
Set objPestanas = RibbonXml.createNode(1, "tab", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui")
Set objPestanas = RibbonXml.createElement("tab")
objPestana.appendChild objPestanas
Set objPestanaAtt = RibbonXml.createAttribute("id")
objPestanaAtt.Text = ("1")
objPestanas.setAttributeNode objPestanaAtt
Set objPestanaAtt = RibbonXml.createAttribute("label")
objPestanaAtt.Text = ("A Custom Tab")
objPestanas.setAttributeNode objPestanaAtt
Set objPestanaAtt = RibbonXml.createAttribute("visible")
objPestanaAtt.Text = ("true")
objPestanas.setAttributeNode objPestanaAtt

'Grupos
Set objGrupo = RibbonXml.createNode(1, "group", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui")
'Set objGrupo = RibbonXml.createElement("group")
objPestanas.appendChild objGrupo
Set objGrupoAtt = RibbonXml.createAttribute("id")
objGrupoAtt.Text = ("dbCustomGroup")
objGrupo.setAttributeNode objGrupoAtt
Set objGrupoAtt = RibbonXml.createAttribute("label")
objGrupoAtt.Text = ("A Custom Group")
objGrupo.setAttributeNode objGrupoAtt

'Control
Set objControl = RibbonXml.createNode(1, "control", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui")
'Set objControl = RibbonXml.createElement("control")
objGrupo.appendChild objControl
Set objControlAtt = RibbonXml.createAttribute("idMso")
objControlAtt.Text = ("Paste")
objControl.setAttributeNode objControlAtt
Set objControlAtt = RibbonXml.createAttribute("label")
objControlAtt.Text = ("Built-in Paste")
objControl.setAttributeNode objControlAtt
Set objControlAtt = RibbonXml.createAttribute("enabled")
objControlAtt.Text = ("true")
objControl.setAttributeNode objControlAtt

RibbonXml.Save ("miRibbon1.xml")
```

End Sub

thanks to all